# How to implement pub/sub class in PHP?

Tags: php, callback, publish-subscribe

I have an EventEmitter class as follows:

How do I implement the publisher method (emit) to loop through all the events and call them? (while making sure all callbacks are always safe to call)

```
class EventEmitter {

    private static $events = array(); // all subscriptions

    public function __construct() {}

  // calls the last subscription on the stack

    public function emit() {

    }

  // adds subscriptions to the stack

    public function subscribe($name, $callback) {

      if(empty(self::$events[$name]))
        self::$events[$name] = array();

      array_push(self::$events[$name], $callback);
    }

}

$emitter = new EventEmitter;

$error_callback = function($data) {
    echo "Error 1. {$data["message"]} \n";
};

$error_callback2 = function($data) {
    echo "Error 2. {$data["message"]} \n";
};

$success_callback = function($data) {
    echo "SUCCESS! {$data["message"]} \n";
};
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. You're creating three variables that contains callbacks, but you're not doing anything with them? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Use `callable` type hint.

Comment: How do instances make sense when relying on `static $events` array and no instance property is present?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `static $events` is the right approach either, I'm stuck at writing the emit function (the publish method)

Comment: `emit` has no `$event_name` argument. First you want *"to loop through all the events and call them"*, then you want to `// calls the last subscription on the stack`. Contradictory.

Comment: Consider `interface` instead of functions since there's no easy/lightweight way to ensure function signatures on callbacks except expensive reflection.